# Any idea why contexts are not showing in template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So, I have this two function in my views.py

```
class TheirDetailView(DetailView):
    model = List
def listcomments(request): 
    modell = Review.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/list_comment.html', {'model' : modell})
```

And have these two paths set in my apps urls

```
    path('list/<slug:slug>/', TheirDetailView.as_view(),name='list_detail'),
    path('comment/',views.listcomments, name='ListComments'),
```

So I have two templates
list_detail.html
&
list_comment.html

Here in list_detail.html I have included list_comment.html (just the comment section is there in list_comment.html)

In my list_detail.html

```
..
...
....
<div class="commentss" id="comments-id">
        <div class = "commentscarrier">
            <div class="comment-contentsas comment-head"><p>Comments(3)</p></div>
            <hr>
            {% include "app/list_comment.html" %}
...
..
```

In my list_comment.html

```
{% load static %}
{% for i in model %}
<div class="comment-contentsas"><p class="commentor-name">{{i.user.username}}
    </p></div>
    <div class="comment-contentsas"><p>{{i.comment}}</p></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In my models.py

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)
    List = models.ForeignKey(List, models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.comment)
class List(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField('Genre')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = RichTextField(null=True,default=' ')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="Movie")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 300,null=True, blank = True, unique=True)
```

I have created 5 objects of Review model manually in admin. So that should show in my template. But its not showing anything. I am guessing I must have been messed up in my urls. But cant exactly figure out what. Sorry if my question is too immature. Beginner here.

Comment: Assuming that you use `manage.py runserver`, please share the output that is generated by this command in the console when you open your page in the browser. Very often this contains helpful error messages and other info.

Comment: No error message there. Its empty. And the output is also empty in the template. I mean I set some dummy comments to check if my include is working. It is working. But seems like its not getting the contexts from the function

Comment: In your views you write modell (with double L) and in the template you have model (with one L), you think that might be the error?

Comment: No i guess. Thats the value 'modell'. Context name is model. And thats what I called from template. So i dont think thats the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from reddit

User - stratified_n_fold

So you are using class based views. Okay update your code with this piece of code

```
class TheirDetailView(DetailView):

model = List

def get\_context\_data(self, \*\*kwargs):        

context = super().get\_context\_data(\*\*kwargs)          

modell = Review.objects.all() 

context\["model"\] = modell        

return context
```

Answer (score 0):

With your `TheirDetailView`, the attribute `model` of the class doesn't mean that there will be a context variable of the same name available in the template. Instead, what will be available in the context is the variable `object` (its value will be the one `List` instance that is fetched for the given `slug`). See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/).